# Getting Error message "PostScript Error : INVALIDFONT" when we try print from Android App using Android print framework

Tags: android, printing

We are getting the error message

> PostScript Error : INVALIDFONT

on the printed document when we try print from Android App using Android print framework.

After some analysis, we found that Android print framework is using its own font (i.e Roboto ) which is not available on Lexmark printers. We have tried to pass some known old fonts like (Arial, Times Roman etc.) to android print framework but it is simply ignoring and considering its own font for print.  Unfortunately Android print framework does not allow one to customize the font, whereas it is allowing other attributes like Media size, Margins, Resolution etc.

Could you please help us on this.

Comment: You could add some more details, including code. Please check here on how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: improved tags, formatting and spelling

Comment: I doubt the problem is as you describe. If the font were not present in the PostScript then you would get a substitute font. The 'invalidfont' error suggests to me that you have a **broken** font embedded in the Postscript program. You should capture the PostScript program before its sent to the printer and put it somewhere public, then post a link to it here. If the Android print framework is creating a PostScript program with an embedded broken font, then you would need to take that up with Google to get it fixed.